# Log ssh script timestamp of execution to file on the server

Tags: linux, bash, logging, ssh

I have a script that executes some commands remotely, every time it runs it appends the time of execution to a log. I thought I was doing it right but then realized the script was sending the time/date of my machine, not using the server time/date in the log.

This is the command I'm using right now:

```
ssh root@myserver "echo \"*** Log info of $(date -u) ***\" >> /var/log/app.log"
```

I tried using single quotes but it does not work at all the script shows an error.

Is there a better way to log that time to a file on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the full command inside single quotes like this:

```
ssh root@myserver 'echo "*** Log info of $(date -u) ***" >> /var/log/app.log'
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! but with double quotes i was able to insert line changes at the end of the echo, now with the single quotes i can't send a multiline command, is there a way to do that with single quotes or should i just send another ssh echo to the file with the empty lines?

Comment: your command works as it is my bad i had a typo with a remaining double quote from the old version, thanks again

Comment: Bash interpolates anything inside of double quotes, so it didn't pass the whole command to the remote server. Instead, it executed the echo and date commands on the remote server, sending the stdout to your local shell. That, in turn, was appended to your local log.

Comment: You could add another remote command onto the end, inside the single ticks, separating the commands with either ";" or "&&". For example, before the closing single quote, try adding an ls command and see if it shows you your local or remote directory. If you put "; ls" before the ending single quote, it will be remote. After the single quote, the ls will be local.